# How to center an element within a span in Bootstrap when the span includes other elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the latest responsive Bootstrap.

So say I have multiple elements within a single span, how would I center ONE element within that span?

My test site is up at [shifteddd.com](http://www.shifteddd.com)

I currently have the info icon in a seperate span to the £10 text, but wouyld like them to be in the same span. How would I go about centering the £10 text and having the info icon slightly padded to the right. I've tried pagination centered and whatnot, but they only seem to work on spans directly, not individual elements within spans.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Bootstrap has Alignment classes which can be seen on this page: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#typography I'd imagine you'd be best placing the £10 and the icon in a span with "display: inline-block" and seeting it to "margin: 0 auto;". Maybe consider using Bootstrap's bundled icons as well or maybe use Font Awesome which integrates perfectly with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I think nesting your spans could work. Using the small spans. See example below:

```
<div class="span6">
        Fluid 6
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
          <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This link is useful. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html